# += operation overloading, self concatenation

Tags: c++

First of all forgive me, but the code was too long and copied from code::blocks, so there was no indentation, I used pastebin, this is the class:
http://pastebin.com/auY5PnFw
In this class I have a list, the += operator overloading is here:

```
List<T>& operator+= (List<T>& l)
{
    List<T>* ptr;
    ptr=l.next;
    while(ptr!=&l)
    {
        this->push(*ptr->info);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    return (*this);
}
```

The problem is with self concatenation, let's say that I have a List l1, and this list has some values inside it.If I say: l1+=l1 , trying to compile a program I see that the program goes into an infinite loop.
I tried to reason over this,since the arguments is l1, called by reference, is valid that this==&l.
So ptr point to l.next, but also to this->next.
I read all info and push values into the list, I don't know why it goes into an infinite loop,I have no idea.

Comment: Use a debugger and single step.  Watch the size of your list as you do.  What is the value of `ptr` when the list has doubled in size?  What happened to `ptr->next` of what was originally the last node in the list?

Comment: The size of the list increases, if I keep it go for few seconds I get something like 25,000 of size.

Comment: Think about my other two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are implementing the `List<T>` so you have access to its internals: Just implement concatenation in thers of copying a list:

1. copy the list passed as argument
2. attach the start of the copy to the end of the current list
3. dreach the list from the copy to avoid realease of the moved nodes

From the looks of it you don't distinguish betwwen the lust and its nodes: although this is doable it generally works better if you have a handle for the list which points to the sequence of nodes.

Comment: Yup, modifying the end node last is a great way to avoid the problem.

Comment: I can do the copy, but I can not get why it does not work.Also, I know when I get the last node becase this node info is a NULL pointer.

Comment: I had a brief thought about using a sequence of iterators e.g. for `std::list<T>` but I suspect that this may have a moving end! That is, even when getting the `end()` iterator just once it would be never reached.

Comment: Every time you append a node the list becomes one element longer. That is, when you appended the first element of the list to its end you still have as much work ahead of as before appended it. This won't ever change unless you know which was the end of the original list to stop there. The NULL in this element is long gone by the time you reach it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Pretty sure you'd need to save `end()-1` or `rbegin()` instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it doesn't reach the end of the list, never.So I saved length list value and used a for to insert all values.